# How to set the excel border to blank in c#

Tags: c#, ssis, office-interop, excel-interop

Basically, I am using a script task within SSIS to format excel cells. My excel template contains blank formatting for the cells like this :[image: Excel cells with no border].

But when I add a row using c# code in the script, the formatting appears like this:
[image: New Row formatting].

I have tried setting the border to none using the following script:

```
_borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
_borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
_borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
_borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
```

_borders here is of type Excel.Borders
I have also tried setting weight and Value = 0. Nothing seems to work.
But this does not accomplish what I want. Any Idea how to do this? I dont want to set the line color to white. I just want it blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got no answers to this one, figured out that I needed to uncheck the "show grid lines" check box. Felt it may help someone trying to do this.